# How to perfectly center image with elements

Tags: html, css, css-position

How can I make img or element with image background same height, padding and margin as other links?

Here is my code

```
  a   {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 1%;
      border: 1px solid black;
      color: black;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
    a img {
      height: 15px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .backg {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 1%;
      border: 1px solid red;
      color: black;
      background-image: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/user_male2-512.png");
      background-size: 100%;

    }
```

here is codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQRyOd?editors=1100

Comment: Why are you using `padding: 1%;` if you want the elements to be fixed size?

Comment: I tried it, but I want it to be flexible size.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understood the question but you can add `vertical-align: middle;` to `.backg` and `a img`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if you don't care about older browser you should use flexbox
Here is a decent guide for doing so:

[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I know that, but Im wondering how can I make it for older browsers